# Datatables date sorting in(DD.MM.YYYY.) format

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, datatables

I 've created table using PHP & MySQL with Datatables plugin and I'm trying to sort my columns with DD.MM.YYYY. format but it seems it doesn't work as I would like it. It's sorting using only first number. 
Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
    var datum = day + "." + month + "." + year + ".";
    var doc = day + month + year;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY.');

        $('#pogled_ispu').removeAttr('width').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            scrollY: "500px",
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            paging: false,
            select: true,
            columnDefs: [{
                width: 10,
                targets: 8
            }],
            fixedColumns: {
                leftColumns: 0
            },
            buttons: [
                'colvis',
                'pageLength', {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'Preuzimanje u excel formatu',
                    title: 'Tablični prikaz_' + datum,
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                }, {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'Preuzimanje u PDF formatu',
                    title: 'Prostorno planska dokumentacija',
                    message: 'Prostorno planska dokumentacija ' + datum,
                    pageSize: 'A3'
                }
            ],
            language: {
                "url": "js/Croatian.json",
                buttons: {
                    colvis: '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>',
                    pageLength: 'Broj redova'
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is picture of table data:
[image]

And here is plugin for date time ordering:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment = function ( format, locale ) {
    var types = $.fn.dataTable.ext.type;

    // Add type detection
    types.detect.unshift( function ( d ) {
        return moment( d, format, locale, true ).isValid() ?
            'moment-'+format :
            null;
    } );

    // Add sorting method - use an integer for the sorting
    types.order[ 'moment-'+format+'-pre' ] = function ( d ) {
        return moment( d, format, locale, true ).unix();
    };
};
```

Is it problem in (DD.MM.YYYY.) format. Should I omit last dot?

Comment: i think you pass datetime format as a string into the datatable

Answer (score 0):

try this date format code:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
"order": [[0, "desc"]], //order by date when 1st time table are loaded, based on your date column
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { sType: "date-custom", aTargets: [0] } //targets are based on your date column
],
"aoColumns": [
    {"mDataProp": "date" //your date column name in array
        ,"mRender": function(data, type, full)
        {
            var getData = new Date(data);
            var month = getData.getMonth() + 1;
            var date = getData.getDate();
            var year = getData.getFullYear();

            return (date > 9 ? date : "0" + date) + "." +
                   (month > 9 ? month : "0" + month) + "." + 
                   year;
        }
    }
]
});

$.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"date-custom-pre": function(a) {
var x;
try {
    var dateA = a.replace(/ /g, '').split(".");


    var day = parseInt(dateA[0], 10);
    var month = parseInt(dateA[1], 10);
    var year = parseInt(dateA[2], 10);
    var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    x = date;
}
catch (err) {
    x = new Date();
}
   return x;
},
"date-custom-asc": function(a, b) {
   return a - b;
},
"date-custom-desc": function(a, b) {
   return b - a;
}});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using ORDER BY on your MySQL statement?

I have managed to sort my columns by date using 'ORDER BY date DESC' within the MySQL SELECT statement. It will order the data you are selecting, so when you pass the data to datatables it will already be ordered by the date.

Example:

```
SELECT column1, column2, datecolumn, column4
FROM table
ORDER BY datecolumn DESC
```

Comment: No, that's definitely not a problem but nevertheless thank you for your effort :)